# How to add even vertical spaces after minipages

Tags: spacing

I would like to add even vertical spaces after minipages in a same page.
In other words, vertical spaces between adjacent minipages, the vertical space between the last minipage and the bottom of a page should be the same.

Expected page layout:
[image: expected page layout]

When all minipages can be put into 1 page, the typesetting is expected.
But when all minipages spread to multiple pages, there is no vertical space after the last minipage in a page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\foreach \img / \imgw / \imgh in {{xxx.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.7\textheight}}} {
    \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
        \includegraphics[width=\imgw,height=\imgh]{\img}%
    \end{minipage}\par\vfill%
}

\end{document}
```

The output from the above code is:
[image]

How to achieve the expected layout?

---

### Edit: Experiments with proposals

Because a minipage may contain text, caption and image in my real TeX source, I tried proposals:

- `\vspace*{\fill}\pagebreak[0]` from @egreg
- `\vfill\null` from @Herbert

When a minipage only contains image, layouts looks the same.
When a minipage contains 1 line text and an image, layouts looks the same.

But when a minipage contains a caption and an image, `\vspace*{\fill}\pagebreak[0]` gives more compact layout, while `\vfill\null` gives relative loose layout.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}


\foreach \img / \imgw / \imgh in {{xxx.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}}%
                                  } {
    \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
        \captionof{figure}{This is a caption}
        \includegraphics[width=\imgw,height=\imgh]{\img}%
    \end{minipage}\par\VFILL_PLACEHOLDER
}

\end{document}
```

- `\vspace*{\fill}\pagebreak[0]` as `\VFILL_PLACEHOLDER`
  [image]
- `\vfill\null` as `\VFILL_PLACEHODER`
  [image]

And the question is how `/null` changes space behavior?

Comment: Use `\vspace*{\fill}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\vfill` is discarded at a page break, `\vspace*{\fill}` isn't.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\foreach \img / \imgw / \imgh in {{xxx.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}}} {%
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
        \includegraphics[width=\imgw,height=\imgh]{\img}%
    \end{minipage}\par\vspace*{\fill}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to break pages in the process, you can add `\pagebreak[0]`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\foreach \img / \imgw / \imgh in {{xxx.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.2\textheight}},
                                  {yyy.png/{\linewidth}/{0.7\textheight}}} {%
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
        \includegraphics[width=\imgw,height=\imgh]{\img}%
    \end{minipage}\par\vspace*{\fill}\pagebreak[0]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @diabonas Fixed

Comment: I have made some experiments, and it looks the proposal is stable in various scenarios. I have add experiments under  'Edit: Experiments with proposals' of the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
    \end{minipage}\par\vfill\null % add empty box
```

[image]

Comment: When a minipage contains a caption, it seems the layout is too loose. New experiment is under 'Edit: Experiments with proposals' of the question.

Answer (score 3):

*And the question is how `\null` changes space behavior?* The answer:

`\vspace*{\fill}\pagebreak[0]` does `\penalty10000\vfill\penalty0` at TeX primitive level. The penalties have zero dimensions, i.e. there is only `\vfill` from dimensions point of view.

`\vfill\null` does `\vfill\hbox{}` at TeX primitive level. And if the `\hbox` is put to the main vertical list, the `\baselineskip` is typically added (not whole baselineskip, it depends on the depth of the previous box). So, there is `\vfill` plus a dimension from `\baselineskip`. That is bigger than the first case, it is not the same.

Moreover, the second case does not include `\nobreak` (alias `\penalty10000`) before `\vfill`, so the page break can be occur at `\vfill` and `\vfill` is removed. But first case keeps `\vfill` and the page break can be done at `\penalty0` only.